# unable to get desired json format while creating laravel 5 api

Tags: json, api, laravel-5

i have the following `Template` model and `TestCategory` hasMany `Test`:

```
class Template extends Model
{
protected $table = 'test_templates';

protected $fillable = [
    'customers_id',
    'tests_categories_id',
    'tests_id'
];

public function customers(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customers_id');
}

public function testCategories(){
    return $this->belongsTo(TestCategory::class, 'tests_categories_id');
}

public function tests(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Test::class, 'tests_id');
}
}
```

And I have the following `index` method defined in `TemplateController`

```
public function index($customerId)
{
$templates = Template::with( 'customers','testCategories','tests')
                      ->where('customers_id', $customerId)->get();
$templates = $templates->groupBy('tests_categories_id');
$templates = json_decode($templates, true);
$templates = array_values($templates);
return response()->json(['Status' => True, 'template' => $templates]);
}
```

I got the following json output:

```
{
"Status": true,
"template": [
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "customers_id": 1,
            "tests_categories_id": 1,
            "tests_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "customers": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Queen PVT.Ltd",
                "address": "gotham",
                "contact_number": "9842********",
                "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43"
            },
            "test_categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "General Tests",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "tests": {
                "id": 1,
                "tests_category_id": 1,
                "name": "Lamination",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "customers_id": 1,
            "tests_categories_id": 1,
            "tests_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "customers": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Queen PVT.Ltd",
                "address": "gotham",
                "contact_number": "984*******",
                "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43"
            },
            "test_categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "General Tests",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "tests": {
                "id": 2,
                "tests_category_id": 1,
                "name": "Paper Type",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "customers_id": 1,
            "tests_categories_id": 2,
            "tests_id": 8,
            "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "customers": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Queen PVT.Ltd",
                "address": "gotham",
                "contact_number": "984******",
                "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43"
            },
            "test_categories": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Scratch Test",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "tests": {
                "id": 8,
                "tests_category_id": 2,
                "name": "HRN Visibility",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        }
    ]
]
}
```

I want to collect all the `tests` as per the `test_categories` without reprinting `customers` and `test_categories` as following:

```
{
"Status": true,
"template": [
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "customers_id": 1,
            "tests_categories_id": 1,
            "tests_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "customers": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Queen PVT.Ltd",
                "address": "gotham",
                "contact_number": "984*****",
                "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43"
            },
            "test_categories": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "General Tests",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "tests": {
                {
                "id": 1,
                "tests_category_id": 1,
                "name": "Lamination",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
                },
                {
                "id": 2,
                "tests_category_id": 1,
                "name": "Paper Type",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "customers_id": 1,
            "tests_categories_id": 2,
            "tests_id": 8,
            "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:44",
            "customers": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Queen PVT.Ltd",
                "address": "gotham",
                "contact_number": "984265*****",
                "created_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43",
                "updated_at": "2018-09-10 11:03:43"
            },
            "test_categories": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Scratch Test",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "tests": {
                {
                "id": 8,
                "tests_category_id": 2,
                "name": "HRN Visibility",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
]
}
```

Comment: Your actual and expected outputs are the same, so I think you made a mistake there. If you fix that hopefully someone should be able help you.

Comment: `tests` attribute is different. I want to collect all the `tests` as per the `test_categories`

Comment: You really want someone to look at every minute detail, explain what's different

Comment: I want to get `{Template : { customer : {}, test_category : { tests:{tests1, test2}}}`  but I am getting `{Template1 : { customer : {}, test_category : { tests:{tests1}},Template2 : {customer : {}, test_category : { tests:{tests2}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly the tests are being separated into different templates when you are expecting some of them to be related to the same template.

This is because your Template class is storing the `test_id` that it belongs to and it can only store 1 test per Template. So when you are calling `Template::with('tests')` it can only return one `Test::class.`

Because you expect to see that many Tests belongTo one Template, and when you look at the relationship from the Template to Test, you expect that a Template has many Tests. Therefore, your Template class should implement the hasMany relationship like so:

```
class Template extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'customers_id',
    'tests_categories_id' // notice the removal of the test_id which should also be removed from the test_templates migration
];
    ...

    public function tests(){
        return $this->hasMany(Test::class); //change belongsTo to hasMany
    }

    ...
}
```

Instead of storing the `test_id` on the Template class you should be storing the `template_id` on your Test class and look something like so:

```
class Test extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'test_template_id' // This should be added to $fillable and the tests migration
    ...
];
    ...

    public function template(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Template::class, test_template_id);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now when you call `Template::with('tests')` it can return many `Test::class` and should match your expected output.